# How to handle an AppStore modal window with Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to **scrape** some data from Version History modal window on AppStore.

For some reason Puppeteer ignores the request. That's how the screen I want to **scrape** looks:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic9p4.jpg)

What I've tried. I have a guess that maybe this modal window is not recognized as a popup.

```
    await page.waitForSelector("div[data-test-we-modal=page-overlay]")
    const link = await page.$('div[data-test-we-modal=page-overlay]')
    const modalPromise = new Promise(x => page.once('popup', x));
    await link.click()
    const modal = await modalPromise; 
    await modal.waitForSelector('button[class=we-modal__close]')
    await modal.click('button[class=we-modal__close]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Some adjustments:

1. It seems popup is a new tab or window, while in your case the dialog is just DOM element with blocking style, so you just need to wait for a selector.
2. The click on the element to open the dialog needs some scripts to be loaded and executed, so additional time or `goto()` load option can help.

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch( { headless: false, defaultViewport: null });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto(
      'https://apps.apple.com/us/app/instagram/id389801252',
      { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' },
    );

    await page.waitForSelector('div[data-test-we-modal=page-overlay] button');
    const link = await page.$('div[data-test-we-modal=page-overlay]');
    await link.click();

    await page.waitForSelector('button[class=we-modal__close]');
    await page.waitFor(3000);
    await page.click('button[class=we-modal__close]');

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Waiting for a selector is the first thing I tried in this case... Console trows back the following error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed` on this line: `await page.waitForSelector('button[class=we-modal__close]')` and if I run this script in a headful mode I don't even see the popup, it it immediately closed.